# When to use singletons in OOP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, singleton

When reading about singletons, I have found this explanation as a reason to use singleton:

> since these object methods are not changing the internal class state, we
>   can create this class as a singleton.

What does this really mean ? When you consider that some method is not changing internal class state ? If it is a getter ? Can someone provide code examples for class that uses methods that are not changing its internal state, and therefore can be used as a singleton, and class that should not be a singleton ?

Usually, when people are explaining singleton pattern, they use DB connection class as an example. And that makes sense to me, because I know that I want to have only one db connection during one application instance. But what if I want to provide an option to force using the new connection when I instantiate DB connection class? If I have some setter method, or constructor parameter that forces my class to open new connection, is that class still a subject to be a singleton ?

I am using PHP, but may understand examples written in JAVA, C#...

This is the [article reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html#advanced-practical-usage). You can ctrl+f search for "internal". Basically, autor is explaining why FileStorage class is a good candidate to be a singleton. I do not understand this sentance

> "These operations do not change the internal class state, so we can
>   create its instance once and use it multiple times."

and therefore I do not understand when to use singletons.

In their example, they have some FileStorage class :

```
class FileStorage
{
    public function __contruct($root) {
        // whatever
    }

    public function read() {
        // whatever
    }

    public function write($content) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

And they say that this class can be a singleton since its methods read() and write() do not chage internal class structure. What does that mean ? They are not setters and class is automatically singleton ?

Comment: If you want an explanation of why someone likes singletons, you should give more of a reference than an out-of-context sentence fragment. I have no idea what the author means, and you haven't provided enough context to make a good guess.  Perhaps ask the author what they meant.

Comment: Also, you have seven questions here, which shows that the question is not at all clear.  Can you ask a more *specific*, and *code-focussed* question?  Questions like that are more likely to get good, unambiguous answers.

Comment: @EricLippert These are not really a 7 questions, they are all meant to clarify what I am asking as a main question. I will add reference now.

Comment: No, you shouldn't use singletons even for database connections. Global state is pretty much always bad.

Comment: If those methods don't change state, it sounds as if they should be static class methods not ones of a singleton instance. Though every class object is a singleton of course, so the boundaries might be thin.

Comment: @Bergi how about in service locators, like explained in the reference ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the article. By "singleton" they mean a singleton container in an inversion-of-control framework, not about the singleton class design pattern.

Comment: The point is that the "dependency" which you are "injecting" is a thing that carries no state with it. All it does is modify the world around it.  And therefore there's no difference between any two of them, and therefore you only need one of them. Here, I have two file system objects, both of which can read and write your hard disk.  What's the difference between them? There is none. So why do you need *two*?  You don't. So if you need one at time X, and another one at time Y, you can re-use the one you had at time X without any problem.

Comment: Also, remember that dependency injection, inversion of control, blah blah blah, are five-dollar words for a five cent concept: a class which needs a service provided can either create a service provider itself, or be given the service provider by its caller. We call the latter "dependency injection". All the jargon around it serves to obfuscate and confuse what is really a very simple concept.

Comment: @EricLippert thank you, I did misunderstood what they said.

Comment: What if this file object has a method that changes its property $filePath, or same constructor option. So at time X you write to one place, and at time Y you write at another, then file dependency does cary state with it, and cannot be a singleton container ?

Comment: @black-room-boy: That's right. If state can change, and the consumer of the service depends on it not changing, then you can't re-use the same instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote reads:

> These operations do not change the internal class state, so we can create its instance once and use it multiple times.

This means that the object in question has no interesting internal state that could be changed; it’s just a collection of methods (that could probably be static). If the object has no internal state, you don’t have to create multiple instances of it, you can keep reusing a single one. Therefore you can configure the dependency injection container to treat the object as a singleton.

This is a performance optimization only. You could create a fresh instance of the class each time it’s needed. And it would be better – until the object creation becomes a measurable bottleneck.

Comment: But when do you consider that object has internal state ? When it is modifying its properties ?

Comment: Internal state = instance variables, properties, or whatever they are called in your language of choice. It’s best when you don’t have to care about that, though, because it’s an assumption that can break later without you noticing. That’s why I said you should _only_ care about these things once you hit an obvious performance problem.

Comment: Now a days i see common pattern i.e. Objects(generally services) does not have state are made singleton irrespective their creation is measurable bottleneck or not . In fact by making classes singleton , they enforce developer does not keep any state in them :)